# What does .call do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I [came across](https://github.com/railscasts/386-authorization-from-scratch-part-2/blob/master/forum-after-split/app/models/permissions/base_permission.rb#L5) this method, where in the end `.call` is used:

```
def allow?(controller, action, resource = nil)
  allowed = @allow_all || @allowed_actions[[controller.to_s, action.to_s]]
  allowed && (allowed == true || resource && allowed.call(resource))
end
```

But [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html#method-i-call) don't really give me the understanding of when/how to use `.call`.

Comment: `@allow_all` contains `true` if set.

Comment: But when it isn't `true ` it contains a proc retrieved from a (hash?). You use `call` when you want to call (i.e., execute) the proc. This is a version of the command pattern, where the "command" name is an array of the controller and action names. The docs seem pretty clear.

Comment: When asking a question like this, it's really important to show what work you have done to answer this question yourself before asking. What did you read? What did you try? As is, it is hard to tell that you researched the problem before asking.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The purpose of the `.call` method is to invoke/execute a `Proc/Method` instance. The example below might make it more clear.

```
m = 12.method("+")
# => `method` gets the `+` method defined in the `Fixnum` instance
# m.class 
# => Method

m.call(3)    #=> 15
# `3` is passed inside the `+` method as argument 
m.call(20)   #=> 32
```

In the above example, `Fixnum` 12 has the method `+` defined.

**In the example you posted:**

```
def allow?(controller, action, resource = nil)
  allowed = @allow_all || @allowed_actions[[controller.to_s, action.to_s]]
  allowed && (allowed == true || resource && allowed.call(resource))
end
```

`@allowed_actions[[controller.to_s, action.to_s]]` returns a `Proc` instance and `resource` is a `param/argument` to the method call.

For example:

```
hash = {[:controller, :action] => 'value'}
# => {[:controller, :action]=>"value"} 

> hash[[:controller,:value]]
# => nil 

> hash[[:controller,:action]]
# => "value"
```

**FYI**: In ruby you can have an `Array` as the `Key` of a `Hash` object.